# Does mysql View slow down the server?

Tags: php, mysql, view

I need to do some calculation each time when a user click "View Statistics" link. The calculation is based on a query. It's too complicated for me to figure out how to re-group the query result [I posted a question about this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165060/how-to-re-group-mysql-result) . Now I'm thinking to create a view of MERGE type first. Then, every time when need to show statistics, I can just query from this view.
I have little knowledge about mysql. Not sure if this is the normal way to do the statistics calculation.
**When does the view get updated?** Does it keeps updating whenever a new entry related to this View is posted? Or, it updates only when being queried? 
**Should I delete the view every time after calculation?**

Comment: VIEW it is pre-complied sql statment, so it will save compilation time ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use stored procedures as an alternative to views. This way you know that your data is freshly grabbed from your tables.

Comment: what is stored procedures? how to do it?

Comment: A stored procedure is basically a function (like in PHP). You can name it as you wish and assign it a SQL you would like to execute and you can call it from your code. Here are some references you can use: http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~yarowsky/600.415.stored-procedures/mysql-storedprocedures.pdf

Comment: I see. so, create the view when need it, and then, delete it after calculation?

Comment: I don't know what language your are using but here is an example of calling a stored procedure from PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

Comment: Well a view isn't up to date with your tables. So a view is more helpful when structuring your data or complex SQLs. A view is pretty much one time use

Comment: yes, I use php. So, can I query from this stored procedure similiar to quering from database? (of course, using the php code in the link you provided)

Comment: Yes, the code is very similar with querying the table, only you don't use Select from 'table' you will use Call 'stored procedure name'

Comment: However I just did a test on views, I updated and inserted new data and the view keeps up to date when I call it. If you declare a view on your database and call it from your code with: SELECT * FROM view_name; the data grabbed will be up to date with your database

Comment: I recommend going with views on this one. There are more flexible than stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks! I will go with view then.

Answer (score 0):

A view is not updated when data is inserted, it is simply a predefined query you can use.

If you have a need for complex calculations to create statistics, maybe create one or more triggers to help you to maintain a statistics table